# Qt4 Azure Database connection using Sqlite Driver

Tags: qt, sqlite, azure

Is it possible to access Azure Database in Qt4 using QSqlite Driver? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome

Answer (score 0):

So you're asking about the QT4. Very nice.!
As far a i know it is possible how? use the GMG method you know what i mean right?
Mr. Junnel.
if you don't know the meaning od GMG post new Thread ok?
Thanks hope i helped you :D.
Kindly click the resolve button :D

Comment: but as far as i know, sometimes GMG method is not applicable on all cases.